How to run Vue (Vue Cli/webpack) monorep sub app from root
My app is a simple monorepo structured like so:
root/
|--package.json
|--shared/
  |--configs/
    |--.eslintrc.js
    |--tsconfig.json
  |--types/
  |--ui-components/
|--project1/
   |--src/
      |--App.vue
      |--main.ts
   |--.eslintrc.js
   |--package.json
   |--project1.code-workspace
   |--tsconfig.json
   |--vue.config.js
|--project2/
   |--src/
      |--App.vue
      |--main.ts
   |--.eslintrc.js
   |--package.json
   |--project2.code-workspace
   |--tsconfig.json
   |--vue.config.js

I've been trying to use npm "workspaces" to compile the subproject's NPM packages up into the root in the hopes I could run each project from the root with something like "cd project2 && npm start" or "npm start --prefix project2".
Both methods result in this error:
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './src/main.js' in '/Users/foobar/code/myapp/project2'
So is there a way to have all my NPM packages and configs in the root dir, and run each app (in those sub dirs).
Is there a native way to do this, where my root dir contains all my configs (or base configs which are extended downstream) like my package.json, vue.configs.js, .eslingrc, tsconfig ect but I can serve and build each projects in the subdirs or do I need something like Lerna?
Should my app look like this?
root/
|--package.json
|--.eslintrc.js
|--tsconfig.json
|--vue.config.js
|--shared/
  |--types/
  |--ui-components/
|--project1/
   |--src/
      |--App.vue
      |--main.ts
|--project2/
   |--src/
      |--App.vue
      |--main.ts


"Should my app look like this?" - no, you'll have problems with this structure, the first one is ok. The question lacks  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it's not evident that the workspaces are the problem. E.g. the error says './src/main.js', but you have .ts . Please, provide a way to reproduce
